# How to get the present working directory on Linux in Java 

Tags: java, linux, bash, working-directory

I am invoking the command using a bash shell in Linux. This command completes its operation using a Java class. I want to retrieve the present working directory from where the command is invoked. When I am using `System.getProperty("user.dir")` I am getting the path from where the Java class is invoked. Can anyone help in this.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to pass the directory in from the shell to the JVM on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

```
new File(".")
```

You can then call getAbsolutePath or whatever you like.

Comment: I believe that will assume the same directory as user.dir, which the OP said was not what s/he wanted.